# Euler Lagrange variational problem with $n$ independent variables and up to the hessian term

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm trying to evaluate Euler Lagrange equation from the following relation:
$$
F[f(\vec{r})]=\int_{\vec{r_1}}^{\vec{r_2}} d^n r J[f(\vec{r}),\nabla f (\vec{r}),H f(\vec{r}) ]
$$

where $H$ is the hessian and $\vec{r}$ represent $n$ independent variables. Our boundary condition is that $\eta $ and its derivatives shout be zero at end points.

what I tried is:

$$
\left [  \frac{\partial F}{\partial \alpha}\right ]_{\alpha=0} =0
$$
and

$$
f(\vec{r},\alpha)=f(\vec{r},0)+\alpha \eta (\vec{r}) \\
\nabla f(\vec{r},\alpha)=\nabla f(\vec{r},0)+\alpha \nabla \eta (\vec{r}) \\
H f(\vec{r},\alpha)=H f(\vec{r},0)+\alpha H \eta (\vec{r})
$$
so we can write
$$
\int_{\vec{r_1}}^{\vec{r_2}}  \left [ \frac{\partial J}{\partial f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}+\frac{\partial J}{\partial \nabla f} \frac{\partial \nabla f}{\partial \alpha}+\frac{\partial J}{\partial H f}\frac{\partial H f}{\partial \alpha} \right ] d^n r \\
\int \left [ \frac{\partial J}{\partial f}\eta(\vec{r})+\frac{\partial J}{\partial \nabla f} \nabla \eta(\vec{r})+\frac{\partial J}{\partial H f} H \eta(\vec{r}) \right ] d^n r
$$
for the second and third terms in bracket I use the integrating by parts. For the second term I wrote:
$$
= \eta(\vec{r}) \frac{\partial J}{\partial \nabla f}-\int \eta(\vec{r}) \nabla .\left ( \frac{\partial J}{\partial \nabla f} \right ) d^n r
$$
 and for the second term including the hessian:
$$
=\nabla \eta(\vec{r}) \frac{\partial J}{\partial H f}-\int \nabla \eta(\vec{r}) \nabla .\left ( \frac{\partial J}{\partial \nabla f} \right ) d^n r\\
 = \eta(\vec{r})\left (\nabla . \frac{\partial J}{\partial H f} \right )+\int  \eta(\vec{r}) \nabla \left ( \nabla .\frac{\partial J}{\partial Hf} \right )d^nr
$$
The terms including $\eta$ and its derivative are zero with regard to the boundary conditions.
Finally we can write the Euler Lagrange equation as:

$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial f(\vec{r})}-\nabla .\left(\frac{\partial J}{\partial \nabla f(\vec{r})}\right )+ \nabla\left ( \nabla .\frac{\partial J}{\partial Hf(\vec{r})} \right )=0
$$
I'm wondering is it true?
Edit: Is it true to integrate from hessian and get gradient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. You can write it explicitly in terms of derivatives, i.e. by seeing the hessian as $\frac{n(n+1)}2$ parameters :

$$
J(Hf)=J(\{\partial _i \partial _j f\})
$$
hence (with summation over repeated indices)
$$\delta J =\frac{\partial^2 J}{\partial _i\partial _j f  }
\delta(\partial _i\partial _j f ) =
\frac{\partial^2 J}{\partial _i\partial _j f  }
\delta\alpha\partial _i\partial _j \eta$$
Integrating by parts twice yields your correct result.

Comment: note enough reputation to vote up. Thanks.